# Can I query the requestAnimationFrame frame rate cap?

Tags: javascript

I have a `setInterval` that has a variable timer (actually a recursive `setTimeout`) for which the interval may be anywhere between 5ms and 1000ms, but it need go no faster than the display frame rate. When the interval approaches the display frame rate (in my case 16ms) I start to see aliasing.

So, when my interval approaches (in my case) 16ms I'd like to switch over to synchronizing with the frame rate by piggy-backing on `requestAnimationFrame`. Similarly, when the interval becomes more than (in my case) 16ms I'd like to switch back to `setInterval`. I can hard code the logic but, it won't work for other displays. Very roughly:

```
// I would like to query this value, not hard code it!
var MIN_FRAME_TIME = 16.666;

var interval = [100];
function call(f) { return f(); }

call(function frame() {
  if (interval[0] <= MIN_FRAME_TIME) {
    callback();
  }
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
});

call(function timer() {
  if (interval[0] > MIN_FRAME_TIME) {
    callback();
  }
  setTimeout(timer, interval[0]);
});

$('#foo').click(function () {
  interval[0] = 5 + Math.random() * 1000;
});
```

Can I query the requestAnimationFrame rate (`MIN_FRAME_TIME` above)? Or, do I have to measure it in situ?

Comment: You have to measure the time between the frames yourself, since the framerate will differ a lot (the browser calls it when it has some spare resources, so not in the millisecond that it is rerendering the dom or something)

Comment: Why not always use animation frames and cap it yourself variably? Should make it all easier and more readable.

Comment: If you want to know the max value of `1/60` (it's always that), you can take a second (literally) after page load and count the iterations.

Comment: The result somewhat surprised me: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/8x107umf/ My count is probably off...

Answer (score 0):

`requestAnimationFrame` already caps to somewhere around 60 frames per second. But if you really need to do this manually you can do it for example like this:

```
var TARGET_FRAME_RATE = 16.666;

var prevTime;

var frame = function () {

    var time;

    draw();

    time = Date.now();

    if (!prevTime || time - prevTime >= TARGET_FRAME_RATE) {
        prevTime = time;
        requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(frame);
        }, TARGET_FRAME_RATE - (time - prevTime));

        prevTime = time;
    }
};

frame();
```

Comment: You can write `(new Date()).getTime()` as `Date.now()` these days. Don't know about speed, but it's shorter at least =)